# have my angular controller check to see what ui-view it's located in with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router with angularjs. I want to write a template for a view that will show a image depending on what the view is. here's my example state.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "",
        views: {

             "topStormtrooper": { 
                templateUrl: '/components/stormtroopers/stormtroopers.html',
                controller: "stormtroopersCtrl"
            },

             "bottomStormtrooper": { 
                templateUrl: '/components/stormtroopers/stormtroopers.html',
                controller: "stormtroopersCtrl"
            }
        }
    })
```

my controller looks like this

```
.controller('stormtroopersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
//   
$scope.stormtrooper = $stateView; //it should be something like this hopefully


}]);
```

The template is all the same just the image will be different depending which view it is loaded into. Currently I just added a new controller for each view and load the image based on that. But I feel like I should be able to do this with just one controller and the controller should be able to detect what the view is. I know you can detect the state but I want go deeper and get the view.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you looking to access the current state in your controller? like
`console.log($scope.stormtrooper) // "index"`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current state configuratin object like this:

`$state.current`

For further information take a look at the [$state](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `$viewContentLoaded` function in your controller as per the [ui-router documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view)

For example:

```
.controller('stormtroopersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams) {

$scope.$on("$viewContentLoaded",function(event,viewName){ //listen for when the content is loaded into the view
    $scope.currentView = viewName;  //assign the view name in a model
    console.log($scope.currentView);
    //do something because you got the view name now....

});

}]);
```

Comment: This seems like the right idea except that the parameter viewName returns undefined. oddly enough it works for me if I use $viewContentLoading except it fires off a event for each view being loaded which makes it impossible to know which view this stormtrooperCtrl is loading in.

Comment: @H0miet which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.4.4

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change your state just for an image in template. You can make it with scope variables.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('stormtrooperCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
//   
  $scope.selected = 0;
  $scope.images = [
    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSz6dBOOsFVAeSilVEIO9dqwrY4R5gCzEMcrRVZguhYhr9PVJsThQ",
    "http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/Wallpaper-Nature-8B71.jpg",
    "http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/1250654-for-laptop-nature.jpg"
  ];


}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="stormtrooperCtrl">
  <button ng-click="selected=0">image1</button>
  <button ng-click="selected=1">image2</button>
  <button ng-click="selected=2">image3</button>
    <div>
      <img width="100" ng-src="{{images[selected]}}"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```